# Docker: passwordless sudo acces in regular shell

Tags: docker, shell, ssh, alpine-linux

Here is my *Dockerfile* for simple access over SSH on 8031 port

```
FROM alpine:latest
    RUN apk add --no-cache php8 \
    php8-common \
    php8-fpm \
    php8-pdo \
    php8-opcache \
    php8-zip \
    php8-phar \
    php8-iconv \
    php8-cli \
    php8-curl \
    php8-openssl \
    php8-mbstring \
    php8-tokenizer \
    php8-fileinfo \
    php8-json \
    php8-xml \
    php8-xmlwriter \
    php8-xmlreader \
    php8-simplexml \
    php8-dom \
    php8-pdo_mysql \
    php8-pdo_sqlite \
    php8-tokenizer \
    php8-pecl-redis \
    php8-pdo_pgsql \
    php8-gd


    RUN apk add --update --no-cache openssh 
    RUN apk add sudo
    RUN echo 'PasswordAuthentication yes' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    RUN echo 'Port 8031' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    RUN adduser -h /home/userdev -s /bin/sh -D userdev
    RUN echo '%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' > /etc/sudoers.d/wheel
    RUN adduser userdev wheel
    RUN echo -n 'userdev:mypassword' | chpasswd
    ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
    RUN apk --update --no-cache upgrade \
    && apk add bash \ 
    && apk add nano \ 
    && apk add nodejs npm \
    && apk add gmp gmp-dev \
    && apk add git htop \
    && apk add mc nano \
    && apk add acl screen
    RUN mkdir -pv /var/www/html
    RUN setfacl -R -m u:userdev:rwX /var/www/html
    COPY .screenrc /home/userdev/
    COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

   EXPOSE 8031
   COPY entrypoint.sh /
```

*entrypoint.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh-keygen -A
exec /usr/sbin/sshd -D -e "$@"
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
name: docker-openssh-server
services:
  openssh:
    image: alpine-sshd-final:latest
    
    ports:
    - "8031:8031"
    network_mode: "host"  
    
    volumes:
    - /var/www/html:/var/www/html
    - ./sshd_config:/etc/ssh/sshd_config 
networks:
  default:
    name: docker-openssh-server_default
```

Everything is working as it should when I'm connecting to the SSH daemon-I can run `sudo -i` without a password.

But when I run  `docker exec -it -u userdev:userdev container_name /bin/bash` sudo asks for password?

Why is this happening there and is it possible to make it passwordless in the second case too?

Comment: This seems more like a virtual-machine setup, and you might use a tool like Vagrant to provision your developer VM.  Giving a user unrestricted root permissions with a hard-coded password written down in plain text isn't usually a good security practice.  Normally a Docker container only runs a single process, and you can control the user it runs as with the `docker run -u` option; you shouldn't usually need `sudo` in Docker at all.

Comment: (If you want to `docker exec` a command as root, `docker exec -u root ...`, but remember that anything you do inside that container will get lost as soon as the container exits.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is really simple: I've to execute `docker exec -it -u userdev:wheel container_name /bin/bash` and everything works!
As posted [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-passwordless-sudo-acces-in-regular-shell/129071/2)